# 7 to 128 decoder in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, decoder, vivado

I'm new to digital electronics and programming in Verilog particularly. I have programmed some basic programs like 2 to 4 decoder, and 4 to 16 decoder. But I am trying to make an image sensor and say I have a pixel which has a SELECT, which needs to be a 7 to 128 decoder. The decoders I made were using case and if-else statements and I don't think that making 128 bits with that process would be good or intelligent. One of the methods could be if I combined a 4 to 16 and a 3 to 8 decoder, for that too, I think I'd need 2 layers(I think 1 single layer might not cover the entire 128 bits), and I don't know how to go ahead with this. Also, is there some other way to make large decoders. I'm sure other ways would be there, which I'm currently unaware of.

Any help with this code would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From my experience the dumber way you make decoder in (e.g. (in==0) then (in==1) then (in==3) etc), the better compiler optimization you would get. The point is that not *you* perform optimization, but compiler will optimize the circuit for you. Because compiler knows very well what is the best way to implement the circuit given device you use. If you start implemeting optimizations yourself, it *may* confuse the compiler. This is NOT to say that you should not perform "optimizations" on the circuit *architecture* level.

Answer (score 1):

When you access a memory with an address, the address decoding logic is essentially an N to 2<sup>N</sup> decoder. You can express that as a shift operation

```
wire [127:0] decoded;
wire [6:0] select;

assign decoded = 128'b1 << select;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an 128 bit vector with an index.

```
wire [127:0] imageline;
wire         image_bit;
wire  [ 6:0] select;

   assign image_bit = imageline[select];
```

This will use a lot of resources as it will make a 128 to 1 bit mux.

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit new to all this. Could you please write the complete code and explain the bit vector part as well. I haven't come across it yet.

Comment: No, This site is not a design house, We do not provide complete code. Neither is this an educational site. If you have problem understanding why the above is a 128 to 1 mux you should take some steps back and start studying basic Verilog code.